# chmod() and touch() operations not permitted

Tags: 8, files, caching

After updating drupal8 for 8.7.0 and then to 8.7.1 versions i have next errors:

> Warning: chmod(): Operation not permitted in Drupal\Component\PhpStorage\MTimeProtectedFastFileStorage->save() (line 76 of core/lib/Drupal/Component/PhpStorage/MTimeProtectedFastFileStorage.php).
>
> Warning: touch(): Utime failed: Operation not permitted in Drupal\Component\PhpStorage\MTimeProtectedFastFileStorage->save() (line 100 of core/lib/Drupal/Component/PhpStorage/MTimeProtectedFastFileStorage.php).

This errors appears for all twig templates and only at first time page loaded. For second and other times no errors and template created in cache folder.

I set 777 permission for all files. Checked files owner. Was Reading many forums and nothing ...

Comment: This looks like the core issue https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2712769.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed this problem by updating the file owner; changing the group only is not enough. Before I had *vagrant* as owner, and *www-data* as group. Now *www-data* is both the owner and the group.

But it's still strange for me. If I refresh the page, sometimes files are generated and the warnings go away.

Comment: Yup, permissions is one thing, ownership another.